# Set vbs permissions

Tags: vbscript

I need to set "Read" permission on all folders, subfolders, and files on the local disk, except for the folder "$Recycle.Bin"
How can this be done? Now the permission are distributed on all but how eliminate one of the folders?

This is what I have tried:

```
Function SetSystemDriveRightsVBS( strUPN, strRights )
On Error Resume Next

Set objEnvLocal = WshShell.Environment("Process")
Set FSLocal = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
systemRootFolder = objEnvLocal("SystemRoot")
systemDriveFolder = objEnvLocal("SystemDrive") & "\.."

Set rootFolder = FSLocal.GetFolder(systemRootFolder)
Call Information("Setting Rights on: " & systemDriveFolder, 0)

stdComspec = "cacls """ ' переменная env C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
stdRights =  """ /T /E /C /G " & strUPN & ":" & strRights

' Setting Permissions on SystemDrive, SystemRoot, SystemRoot\system32 folders and there contents, if Administrator has a permission
Call RunEnc( stdComspec & systemDriveFolder  & stdRights, consoleCharset)
Call RunEnc( stdComspec & systemRootFolder  & stdRights, consoleCharset)
Call RunEnc( stdComspec & systemRootFolder &"\System32"  & stdRights, consoleCharset)
Call RunEnc( stdComspec & systemRootFolder &"\SysWOW64"  & stdRights, consoleCharset)

stdRights =  """ /T /E /C /G " & strUPN & ":" & strRights

' A very very long recursive filesystem permission set
'Call SetRightsOnFolderContent(systemDriveFolder,stdComspec,stdRights)

' Обработка ошибок скрипта
If Err <> 0 Then
Call GlobalInformation("Error setting rights on DiskDrive:" & Err.Number & " -- " &  Err.Description)
Err.Clear
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`icacls`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525) for this. Don't bother with `cacls` (it doesn't handle inheritance correctly). And I'd use a batch script, because for a task like this it's much simpler than VBScript (even more since you're shelling out anyway):

```
@echo off
for /d %%d in (C:\*) do (
  icacls "%%~fd" /grant username:(OI)(CI)R /t
)
```

The above will grant read permission on all immediate subfolders of `C:\` that don't have the hidden flag set and their subfolders. This automatically excludes `$Recycle.bin`, but also some other system folders. If you want to grant read permission on those folders as well you'd have to use something like this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('dir /a:d /b C:\') do (
  if not "%%~nxd"=="$Recycle.bin" icacls "%%~fd" /grant username:(OI)(CI)R /t
)
```

You should, however, **think twice** before actually messing with permissions of system folders. On some system folders even admins don't have access, so you'd have to take ownership, and you can **seriously** screw up the system if you change owner or permission to something Windows doesn't like.